# Valgrind error when using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am using valgrind to fix memory leaks in my C program, and there is one particular function that seems to be the source of most of the valgrind errors

```
typedef struct Array {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    void **items;
} Array;

Array *createArray(int capacity) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    array->capacity = capacity;
    array->size = 0;
    void **items = malloc(sizeof(void *) * array->capacity *  sizeof *items);
    if(items == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    array->items = items;
    return array;
}
```

The first line of the `createArray` function is throwing the following error in Valgrind

`1,296 (16 direct, 1,280 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 34 of 42`

Am I not using malloc in the right way to allocate memory?

Comment: your first `malloc` looks just fine.. valgrind is saying "this is the spot where you allocated memory but never `free`d it". Whether you want to or not is up to you,, I know some high rep users here don't worry about manually cleaning up by relying on the OS to cleanup allocated memory once the process exits. Personally I always try to cleanup after myself.

Comment: Why `sizeof (void*)`? (which is `sizeof "a pointer"`) and not `void **items = malloc(array->capacity *  sizeof *items);`? There are no other issues with your allocation. As posted, earlier, if that is a valgrind `'error'`, then it makes little sense, if that is a failure to `free`, then that's all it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed above in the comments, it is unclear why you allocate `items` with:

```
 void **items = malloc(sizeof(void *) * array->capacity *  sizeof *items);
```

(which essentially allocates 8x (an additional multiple of `sizeof "a pointer"`) number of pointers than would be required)

Instead, if you are allocating `array->capacity` pointers for `items`, then use:

```
void **items = malloc(array->capacity * sizeof *items);
```

Your `valgrind` error does not look like an error, but the result of not calling `free` on the memory you allocate, leaving `valgrind` to report the bytes lost (still reachable on exit). You can easily free the memory on exit with a simple `destroyArray` function similar to:

```
void destroyArray (Array *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array->size; i++)
        free (array->items[i]);
    free (array->items);
    free (array);
}
```

Putting it altogether you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Array {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    void **items;
} Array;

Array *createArray (int capacity) {
    Array *array = malloc (sizeof *array);
    array->capacity = capacity;
    array->size = 0;
    void **items = malloc(array->capacity *  sizeof *items);
    if(items == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    array->items = items;
    return array;
}

void destroyArray (Array *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array->size; i++)
        free (array->items[i]);
    free (array->items);
    free (array);
}

int main (void) {

    Array *a = createArray (10);
    printf ("%d capacity\n", a->capacity);
    destroyArray (a);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should also validate `Array *array = malloc (sizeof *array);` succeeded and `(array != NULL)` before attempting to use `array`)

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/allocstruct
==5777== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5777== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5777== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5777== Command: ./bin/allocstruct
==5777==
10 capacity
==5777==
==5777== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5777==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5777==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 96 bytes allocated
==5777==
==5777== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5777==
==5777== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5777== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Look things over and let me know if this is what you were concerned with.